# MongoDB db.collection.insertOne crashing after writing to DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm currently using the 'mongodb' package to connect to a local mongo server but the application keeps crashing after creating a user. The data is been written to the local database but when the promise is calling the callback function the MongoDB package throws an error (authorization is not defined). Any ideas as of why this could be happening?

The server crashes inside the /auth/signup route. Essentially I parse the user input to check that the data provided by the user is in the correct format and then I create the structure that I'll write back to the database. I'm currently writing back a class called User with a structure like this:

```
class User {
  strategy = ...
  email = ...
  displayName = ...
  salt = ...
  password = ...
}
```

After checking that no other user with this particular email has been created, I create the new User instance and insert it into mongoDB as shown below:

```
db.collection('users').insertOne(user, (err, result) => {
        if(err){ return res.status(400).send({ error: 'failed to store new user to DB'}); }

        //respond to request indicating the user was created
        return res.status(200).send({token: authorization.tokenForUser(user)});
      });
```

The application crashed after writing but before the callback. This is the error I'm getting:

```
.../auth/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^

ReferenceError: authorization is not defined
    at db.collection.insertOne (.../auth/routes/authRoutes.js:93:45)
    at result (.../auth/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:410:17)
    at executeCallback (.../auth/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:402:9)
    at insertDocuments (.../auth/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:891:19)
    at handleCallback (.../auth/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at coll.s.topology.insert (.../auth/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:863:5)
    at .../auth/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:397:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
```

I believe the errors has to do with the way I'm using the mongoDB pool I initialize when the application starts running. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is the `authorization.tokenForUser(user)` call and as the error message says, `authorization` is not defined (there is no variable with that name in scope).

Comment: Actually it just means that `authorization.tokenForUser(user)` is throwing `ReferenceError: authorization is not defined` because you don't have that defined in the current scope. That's a JavaScript syntax error which means exactly that. The rest of the stack trace is simply there because the code is inside a **callback**, so nothing to do with MongoDB or the driver itself.

Comment: Where did you defined the `authorization` object?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I was looking for the error in the wrong place. Thanks for the help. The variable was called authentication not authorization.